# Is there any way to get list of all applications opens, and jump to that window

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to get list of all applications opens i.e chrome, notepad etc. and if user selects notepad then jump to that window in WPF.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/648413/16822867)?

Comment: yes, but how can i navigate to that window.. ?

Comment: navigate? you mean activate the windows? give focus?

Comment: yes, i want that window to get into focus

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25578305/c-sharp-focus-window-of-a-runing-program

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: You mean like.. Alt+Tab?

Comment: My goal is to create one window in WPF , on which i can show all the other applications which are currently opened and when user selects any one of them it should jump to that... just like when we do ALT + TAB it shows all the windows

Comment: I flagged this post as duplicate, because it asks 2 questions, both already answered (see the links posted by user16822867)